# Filter text based on two-and-conditions for an if-condition for logstash configuration

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

I have a log file. The log file contains many db-exceptions . I am interested in fetching all exceptions using logstash and index in ElasticSearch

### Exception :

```
05-06-19 05:34:42.794     6a5ba226-da6a-469a-8304-2f79f68fdbcd        http-bio-8080-exec-8     ERROR     c.w.m.n.o.i.o.r.XYZRepo         executeMerge      157     Failed while processing deliveryList:[deliveryTO{deliveryNumber=92183914, itemNumber=565683539, asnNumber='0664420512', channelMethod='SSTKU,CROSSU', baseDivisionName='wm', countryCode='US' itemUomCode='null', poInd='r', obsoleteInd=null, processStatus='null', itemQuantity=null, overageItemQuantity=null, availableQuantity=322, whpkQuantity=null, vnpkQuantity=null, unfulfilledQty=null ,newItemQty=null} ] with exception:{} com.a.b.c.exceptions.MyDBException: ExceptionCode-BE-00028
```

### Logstash filter :

```
filter {
  grok{
      match => { "message" => "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:Date}%{DATA:corelationid}%{LOGLEVEL:loglevel}%{DATA:javaclass}%{NUMBER:number}%{GREEDYDATA:content}" }
      overwrite => ["message"]
 }

  if  ("ERROR" not in [loglevel] and "ExceptionCode-BE-00028" not in [content])  {
       drop { }
  }   
}
```

### Logstash output :

```
output {
stdout {
    codec => dots
} 
elasticsearch {
   index => "db-failure"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you get an error? What is the expected and actual result?